# How can i get a list of the simple products with at least one configuration option?

Tags: magento

I need to get with magento a list of all of the simple products with at least one confgurable option.

What is the condition inside the loop ?

```
<?php require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);

set_time_limit(0);                   // ignore php timeout
ignore_user_abort(true);             // keep on going even if user pulls the plug*
while(ob_get_level())ob_end_clean(); // remove output buffers
ob_implicit_flush(true);             // output stuff directly
//error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* not Mage::run(); */
Mage::app('default');

// get product collection (All product)
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$visibility = array(
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG);

$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility)
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->addStoreFilter($storeId);

foreach ($_productCollection as $pro):
    endforeach;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First I wouldn't use : `addAttributeToSelect('*')` you are going to slow things down.

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/products')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'simple')->addAttributeToSelect('name');
foreach ($products as $product) {
    echo $product->getName(); 
}
```

try that.